# Insufficient Privileges to log in to api store after admin password change

Tags: wso2

I have changed the carbon super user - admin's password in WSO2 API Manager. After doing that I cant log in to API Store. It says "Unable to log you in! Insufficient Privileges." What is the problem here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to modify the  **AuthManager**  section in the api-manager.xml with the new admin password.